# Using a comparator with Treemap causes duplicate keys

Tags: java, hashmap, comparator, treemap

I am using a treemap but created my own comparator so that the treemap is ordered by the values rather than the keys. This works fine but whenever I come to overwrite a <key, value> mapping, instead of being overwritten, a new mapping is added with the same key (which shouldn't happen because maps in Java are meant to have unique keys). I have even tried to remove the mapping first before adding another one but nothing gets deleted from the treemap. When I remove the comparator, there are no unique values and the treemap works as expected. Why does this happen?

Here is my code:

```
public Map<String, List<String>> mapQtToNonSampledCase(List<Entry> cases, Map<String, Integer> populationDistribution) {
  Map<String. Integer> distribution = new HashMap<>(populationDistribution);
  Map<String. List<String>> qtToCases = new HashMap<>();
  
  Comparator<String> valueComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String k1, String k2) {
      int compare = distribution.get(k1).compareTo(distribution.get(k2));
      if (compare == 0)
        return 1;
      else
        return compare;
      }
    };
      TreeMap<String, Integer> sortedByValues = new TreeMap<>(valueComparator);
      sortedByValues.putAll(distribution);
      
      for(Entry entry: cases) {
        List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> listEntries = sortedByValues.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.tolist());
        Map.Entry<String, Integer> qt = sortedByValues.firstEntry().getKey().equals(entry.get(UtilsClass.ID).toString()) ? (listEntries.get(1) != null ? listEntries.get(1) : null) : sortedByValues.firstEntry();
        if(qt != null) {
          if(!qtToCases.containsKey(qt.getKey()) {
              qtToCases.put(qt.getKey(), new ArrayList<>());
            );      
          }
          qtToCases.get(qt.getKey()).add(entry.get(UtilsClass.ID).toString());
          sortedByValues.put(qt.getKey(), qt.getValue() - 1);
          
        }
      }
      // Printing keys
      for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : sortedByValues.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
      }
}
```

And here is the console output (apologies for the quality, it's a picture from another device):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom comparator is not *consistent with equals*: When you try to update a key with a different value, your comparator will return a value != 0, but the keys are the same.

See this comment in [TreeMap API doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html):

> Note that the ordering maintained by a tree map, like any sorted map,
> and whether or not an explicit comparator is provided, must be
> consistent with equals if this sorted map is to correctly implement
> the Map interface.

The term 'consistent with equals' is defined here: [Comparable API doc]:[2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

> The natural ordering for a class C is said to be consistent with equals if and only if e1.compareTo(e2) == 0 has the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 of class C.

Comment: I see, can this logic not be applied to the values? If not, is there a better way to have some data structure that orders the entries based on their values (and would need to be updated since changes are made to those values)?

Comment: Furthermore, is it possible to make my comparator consistent with equals without getting rid of it?